# Files/Entire Network won't "remember forever" my login

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files, networking

When I first logged in to a home network drive, I entered the login and checked the box to "remember forever". But it never remembers and instead requires me to enter login each time. Also, it requires logins for every subdirectory as well.

elementary OS 0.3 Freya (64-bit)
Intel Core i& @ 2.30 GHz x 8

Comment: Are you using Samba?

Comment: No, just the standard out-of-the box system.